# The bootstrap collapse function doesn't seem to work here. Is there something I don't see?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make a navbar that will be collapsing when the window is small, but the button that is supposed to show the menu doesn't do so. In short, the collapse button doesn't work. It is supposed to show a dropdown menu, but it doesn't.

There are no errors in the consoles and I verified that jQuery link is in the right place. I checked js plugin in my browser and jQuery is working for other things as well. I am very new to this, so I will appreciate any comments too.

EDIT:

```
    <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark" id="navbar">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item ">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#jumbotron-picture">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About Me</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#portfolio">My Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#contact-div">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </nav>
```

This is what I have included

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

And my jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // navbar fade-in 
    $(document).ready(function() {

      // hide .navbar first
      $(".navbar").hide();

      // fade in .navbar
      $(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function() {

          // set distance user needs to scroll before we start fadeIn
            var hT = $('#about').offset().top,
            hH = $('#about').outerHeight(),
            wH = $(window).height(),
            wS = $(this).scrollTop();  

        if (wS > (hT+hH-wH) && (hT > wS) && (wS+wH > hT+hH)){
            $('.navbar').fadeIn();

          }         
        });
      });

    });

    //View my work button
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".down").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $("#about").offset().top
        }, 900);
      });
    });
```

Here is my CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
      font-family: 'Open Sans', serif;
      position: relative;

    }



    .jumbotron {
      width: 100wh;
      height: 100vh;
      color: #fff;
      background: rgb(70, 16, 140);
      background: linear-gradient(120deg, rgba(70, 16, 140, 1) 0%, rgba(78, 23, 145, 1) 10%, rgba(76, 33, 134, 1) 18%, rgba(106, 68, 156, 1) 26%, rgba(91, 45, 149, 1) 34%, rgba(106, 64, 159, 1) 39%, rgba(90, 33, 162, 1) 48%, rgba(107, 60, 166, 1) 55%, rgba(100, 39, 176, 1) 62%, rgba(102, 58, 159, 1) 69%, rgba(99, 36, 179, 1) 79%, rgba(85, 36, 149, 1) 85%, rgba(106, 75, 145, 1) 95%, rgba(79, 15, 161, 1) 100%);

      background-size: 400% 400%;
      -webkit-animation: Gradient 10s ease infinite;
      -moz-animation: Gradient 10s ease infinite;
      animation: Gradient 10s ease infinite;
      margin: 0;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes Gradient {
      0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%
      }

      50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%
      }

      100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%
      }
    }

    @-moz-keyframes Gradient {
      0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%
      }

      50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%
      }

      100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%
      }
    }

    @keyframes Gradient {
      0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%
      }

      50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%
      }

      100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%
      }
    }

    span {
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #EBD727;

    }


    .jumbotron h1 {

      align-content: center;

    }

    #jumb-text {

      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
      top: 200px;




    }

    #myPicture {


      margin-top: 50px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      display: block;
      border-radius: 50%;



    }

    #about-text {


      text-align: center;
      color: #343A40;
      border-bottom: 3px solid #EBD727;
      width: 200px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-top: 100px;


    }

    #about-background {

      width: 71%;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-top: 70px;
    }

    .navbar {

      height: 50px;
      border-bottom: 4px solid #EBD727;



    }

    #portfolio {

      background-color: #F5F5F5;

    padding: 10px 30px 50px 30px;


    }

    #portfolio-text {

      text-align: center;
      color: #343A40;
      border-bottom: 3px solid #EBD727;
      width: 230px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-top: 70px;
      padding-top: 50px;

    }


    #img-laser {
      max-width: 47%;


      height: auto;
      margin: auto;

    }

    #img-maze {

      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      margin: 0 auto;

    }

    #card-id {

      background-color: #F5F5F5;
      border: none;

    }

    .contact-div {
      padding-top: 100px;
      padding-bottom: 50px;
      background-color: #252934;
      color: #FEFEFE;

    }

    #email,
    #subject,
    #textarea {

      background-color: #1E242C;

    }

    #view {

      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
      top: 200px;


    }

    #button {

      height: 50px;
      width: 150px;
      transition: all 0.4s;
      background-color: transparent;
      color: #F5F5F5;

    }

    #button:hover {

      background-color: #EBD727;
      color: #343A40;

    }

    #first {

      width: 50%;



    }

    .nav-item > .active a{

      color:#EBD727 !important;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When I changed the navbar-expand-sm to navbar-expand-md it worked.  Also, I believe the data-target and the following id are supposed to match.  I'm new to this also so I'm sorry if I am not much help.

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work for me. I changed my data-target but it didn't work. Thank you for the suggestions though.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was actually very simple. For some reason the background of navbar on dropdown was white and not dark, so I couldn't see it.